# binding multiple services android

Tags: android, service, android-activity, bind

I have an activity that has several services and several activities. I want to be to able to bind activity A with service A, Activity B with Service B, ect. I have been able to bind service and activity A with eachother with no problems. I tried to do service and activity B together the same way I did group A and it DOES NOT work. My question is with the onBind

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

Does this need to be different for each service/activity? I have researched online and have only found binding multiple services to one activity and that isnt what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry i didn't understand your question please elaborate and put some code. and from the android development site for [bound service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) "**When creating a service that provides binding, you must provide an IBinder that provides the programming interface that clients can use to interact with the service.**"

Comment: I found my error, I had a issue in the manifest that I did not catch